# on_ready not called when running Discord Bot (Python)

Tags: python, discord.py

I've been writing my first Discord bot in Python, and it's been working just fine. I decided to refactor my code into two modules instead of just one. It looks like this:

```
Proj
- src
-- __init_.py
-- eve.py
-- event.py
```

My eve.py looks like this:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from discord.ext.commands import Bot
import asyncio
from src.event import eventCall

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="!")

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print ("Booting up your system")
    print ("I am running on " + bot.user.name)
    print ("With the ID: " + bot.user.id)

@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def event(ctx):
    await eventCall(ctx)

bot.run(<client ID>)
```

And my event.py looks has this tag within it:

```
async def eventCall(ctx):

    member = ctx.message.author
    message = await bot.send_message(member, "Hi " + member.display_name + "!")
    channel = message.channel
    (continues)
```

I was struggling to get eve.py to import event.py, so I moved everything up to the src folder and then I no longer go compiler errors.

But now when I run eve.py, on_ready no longer triggers (I don't see any text in my console), and the !event command doesn't work within Discord.

I think both my folder structure and my syntax for using import could be wrong, but I'm unsure how best to straighten this out.

Comment: Comment out the `from src.event import eventCall` line (and maybe all the lines where `eventCall` is referenced).  You should see an exception if the module isn't found though.  Is there any code that is executed in `src.event` that is not in a function?  It will be run when the file is imported, so maybe there is a loop there that is taking a long time?

Comment: That worked! event.py has lots of defs in it, but nothing that wasn't present when it was all in a single module. I updated my post above to show everything within it.

Comment: If `eve.py` and `event.py` are in the same directory, then shouldn't you be importing it with `from event import eventCall` ?

Comment: Whenever I do that, Eclipse doesn't seem to like it. I've also tried .event and that doesn't give me an Eclipse error, but I end up with a: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '__main__.event'; '__main__' is not a package

Comment: maybe the bot isn't running in the first place. `bot.run(<client ID>)`  instead of client ID it should be token, maybe u put it idk.

Comment: It seems like you are using a old version of discord.py, should I recommend you to upgrade to discord.py 2.0?

Answer (score 1):

Consider reading this: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/intents.html#why-does-on-ready-take-so-long-to-fire

TL;DR
As part of the API change regarding intents, Discord also changed how members are loaded in the beginning. Originally the library could request 75 guilds at once and only request members from guilds that have the Guild.large attribute set to True. With the new intent changes, Discord mandates that we can only send 1 guild per request. This causes a 75x slowdown which is further compounded by the fact that all guilds, not just large guilds are being requested.

For solutions, visit that link above

Comment: they propose to turn off chunking but i can't seem it to get it to work even if i copy past the code from the documentation, any suggestions

Answer (score -6):

You have to type "await print" in the on_ready function in eve.py.

Comment: Actually, that's not how it works. You only have to use `await` if you're calling an `async` coroutine. Otherwise, you can use all functions as normal.